# Bootstrap Left Navigation Menu with active class and border

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want to add a active class on left menu when someone clicks on it. I tried following but if I add e.preventDefault() then the link doesn't work and it doesn't show any output. If I remove e.preventDefault() then it gives me the output but active class goes back to Home. Also , I like to add a border in left menu . if you have any solution, let me know . here is code

Html file code

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked span2" >
        <li class="active"><a href="Home.aspx">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="ShreddingStatistics.aspx">Shredding Statistics Report</a></li>
        <li><a href="ShreddingDetailReport.aspx">Shredding Detail Report</a></li>

</ul>
```

Jquery Code

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(".nav.nav-pills.nav-stacked li").click(function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        $(".nav.nav-pills.nav-stacked li").removeClass("active");
                        $(this).addClass("active");

                    }); });
```

Comment: Bootstrap does that by default. What are you trying to do differently?

Comment: If I click on home then home in left navigation should be highlighted . If I click on Shredding Statistics Report then Shredding Statistics Report should be highlighted in left menu and same for the next. It is not happening by default. You need add a active class dynamically when user click on any of the option.

Comment: Your use of `span2` seems to indicate that you're using Bootstrap 2. Is that the case? Tabs and pills certainly do have an active class by default. Please create a demo of your code: http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: I am not able to see Piils and stack behavior in Jsfiddle.net even though I added bootstrap.min.js

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/p2wonm9d/

Comment: It appears that you wish to set the active class based on the URL. This requires a server-side solution or JavaScript that parses the URL. You can't do it with click events as those function objects are lost when the page reloads.

Comment: Yes. I would like to pass the url from li to javasceript function so it will highlight it for that url.  like this but I need something dynmaic .  
            $('.nav').on('click', 'li:has(a[href^="ShreddingDetailReport.aspx"])', function (e) {

                debugger;
                var s = document.location.pathname;

                $('.nav li').removeClass('active');
                $(this).addClass('active');
            })

Comment: That doesn't make sense. If a user clicks the menu, the page is changed. JavaScript is irrelevant. Am I missing something?

Comment: if you have limited number number of pages do it manually